# One ping two results

Tags: linux, bash

I'm sure there is an easy answer to this but not being too fluent in BASH I'm just going round in circles.
I want to do this

```
ping -c1 8.8.8.8 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
SUCCESS=$?
if [ $SUCCESS -eq 0 ]  etc....
```

But then also assign that ping result to a variable so that I can get the time delay

```
ping -c1 8.8.8.8 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null | DELAY=awk '{print $11}'
SUCCESS=$?
if [ $SUCCESS -eq 0 ]  etc....
echo $DELAY
```

Thanks

Comment: check tee command.

Comment: You can't redirect all output to null and hope to get something meaningful in your pipe after that. Also, in my implementation of ping there's no 11th field to be captured. How about some sample output?

Comment: ping -c1 8.8.8.8 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null  | DELAY=awk '{print $11}'
SUCCESS=$?
if [ $SUCCESS -eq 0 ]
    then
    echo "Good $DELAY"
    else
    echo "Fail"
  fi
#EOF

Comment: From 
    64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5150 ttl=123 time=55.4 ms
I want the result
    Good 55.4
or
    Fail
If it had failed

Comment: Google: [bash result of first command in pipe](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+result+of+first+command+in+pipe)

Answer (score 1):

There are multple issues with your code. One is already addressed by tink. If you do

```
ping -c1 8.8.8.8 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null | cat
```

you first put all the stdout of the ping in /dev/null and then hope t get some stdout in your pipe. That won't work.

Second, the syntax

ping -c1 8.8.8.8 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null | DELAY=awk '{print $11}'

is not correct. You will probably get a message

```
-bash: {print $11}: command not found
```

That is: the DELAY=awk syntax is used to set the variable DELAY to 'awk'  for the execution the '{print $1}' command. That is not what you want to do.

Note also, that `$?` is the exit-code of the last command. So, if the previous line would have worked, $? would be the result of the `awk` and no longer of the `ping`.

Finally, when I do a ping, `awk '{print $11}'` just gives me a bunch of empty lines.

So, what to do? Fro example:

```
tempfile=/tmp/tempfile.$$
host=8.8.8.8
ping -c1 $host > $tempfile
success=$?
if [ $success -eq 0 ] ; then
    sed -n 's/.*time=//p' $tempfile
else
    echo "AAaarrghh... My Ping FAILED"
fi
rm $tempfile
```

or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone and yes I knew my code had errors but it was about trying to describe the problem. I ended up going with this:-

```
PING=$(ping -c1 8.8.8.8 2>&1);
SUCCESS=$?
DELAY=$(echo $PING | awk '{print $14}' | awk -F= '{print $2}')
if [ $SUCCESS -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo $DELAY
  else
    echo 0
fi
```